# UITableViewCell and UITextField with user interaction disabled doesn't call didSelectRow

Tags: ios, swift3

My cell has a `UITextField` (bound to all the edges) with `isUserInteractionEnabled` on false. So I expect that when I click the cell the `didSelectRowAt` is called.

Nowm this never happens. It doesn't call the `didSelectRowAt` function.

Is there any way to find out who is consuming my event? Also in the view debugger, I don't see any views on top of it.

Comment: Have you set your VC class a delegate of your tableview? Also have you implemented willSelect by any chance in your code

Comment: Just for debugging, remove all the views from the cell and click it, does it enter the didSelect function?

Comment: Please make sure your tableView "Selection" property is not "No selection"

Comment: I removed all the views and put the cell height on 100 so I just have a white cell when I click on it nothing happens. My tableview delegate is on the viewcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure you implemented UITableViewDelegate.
- Make sure you have not added UITapGestureRecognizer anywhere in your
  view.

Comment: I did. I just found out that when I press the cell and I keep pressing the didSelectRowAt is called... This is weird

Comment: apparently there was a tapgesture on the viewcontroller I didn't know about. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure your VC is delegate of UITableView
- Make sure your tableView selection is not "No Selection"
- And final, try to use

  *textfield.isEnable = false*
  instead of 
  *textfield.isUserInteractionEnable = false*

Comment: My delegates are         tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self and the selection is not disabled. I now even just have a empty cell and it doesn't trigger the didSelect

Comment: do you still can interact with you tableView by scrolling it? If not, maybe your tableView. isUserInteractionEnable set to false or some things over your tableView but transparent. And to make sure, please check the delegate function name is didSelect but not didDeselect

Comment: I have didSelectRowAt and it is called when I keep pressing the cell. Not when I just tap the cell..